# Set environment variable for runcmd

Tags: cloud-init, cloud-config

Using cloud-init, I can specify a `runcmd` section and do something like this:

```js
runcmd: [
  'MYVAR=VALUE some-command --a A --b B'
]
```

This works, and runs `some-command` with `MYVAR` set to `VALUE` in the environment.  It runs under the shell.

However, I actually want to use the parameterized form, like this:

```js
runcmd: [
  [
    'some-command',
    '--a', 'A',
    '--b', 'B'
  ]
]
```

The reason is that some of these parameter values will be dynamically substituted, and I don't want the shell trying to interpret them.

So, I can run commands with this array of strings just fine, but how I can I specify the environment for them?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use the `env` command to accomplish this:

```
runcmd: [
  [
    'env',
    'MYVAR=VALUE',
    'some-command',
    '--a', 'A',
    '--b', 'B'
  ]
]
```

See the [`env` man page](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/env.1.html) for more information.

Comment: Ah, good idea!  Works perfectly, thank you.